# What do I need to be able to take my nephew on a UK domestic flight?

Tags: uk, children, domestic-travel

I'm planning on taking my 6 year old nephew on a domestic flight (Leeds to Cornwall) this summer.

I understand that *if* we were going abroad, I would need a letter of parental/guardian consent. Is this the same for domestic flights? Is there anything else that I need?

I have permission from both parents.

Comment: Which airline? Though I imagine there aren't that many flying leeds to cornwall!

Comment: Probably FlyBE or BritishAirways

Comment: I would get a parental permission letter anyway, in case the police want to question you.  That is just my personal opinion, though.

Answer (score 6):

From [FlyBE's requirements](https://www.flybe.com/checkin/id-requirements/) (much less strict for Domestic travel):

> **Children and domestic travel**
>
> Children under the age of 16 do not need to show ID on domestic
>   routes. The adult they are travelling with can vouch for the
>   infant's/child's identification, providing the relevant photo ID is
>   shown (by the adult). On International routes a passport will be
>   required.
>
> If the child is traveling unaccompanied and aged between 12-16 years,
>   they will be required to produce photographic ID.

So it seems like they're register that there was a child travelling with you, but would rely on you for the identification.  No other document is required.

Again, this is for domestic only.